# Unable to populate a field as expected In jolt transform Like if-else and if-else(nested)?

Tags: json, apache-nifi, nested-loops, jolt

**JSON Input** :

```json
{
  "code": "+91-",
  "status": "A",
  "number": "123456778",
  "country": "I",
  "pukcode": "00-766-54"
}
```

**My Jolt Spec 1** :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=trim",
      "mobile": "=concat(@(1,code),@(1,number),"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "eventInfo": "eventInfo",
      "mobile": {
        "": {
          "comment": [
            "if blank, do not pass mobile"
          ]
        },
        "*": {
          "@(2,mobile)": "eventData.Records.[0].mobile",
          "@(2,status)": {
            "A": {
              "#Active": "eventData.Records.[0].status"
            }
          },
          "@(2,country)": {
            "I": {
              "#India": "eventData.Records.[0].country"
            }
          },
          "@(2,pukcode)": {
            "": {
              "comment": [
                "if blank, do not pass mobile"
              ]
            },
            "*": {
              "@(2,pukcode)": "eventData.Records.[0].pukcode"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**output** :

```json
{
  "eventData" : {
    "Records" : [ {
      "mobile" : "+91-123456778",
      "status" : "Active",
      "country" : "India"
    } ]
  }
}
```

To the above Input I need to Populate the Data based on mobile number existence then only it should populate all the fields and puk-code code should also populate when input data is prasent in the input by target to mobile. But here the Problem pukcode is not getting populate even when the field consist Input data.

**My Jolt Spec 2** :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=trim",
      "mobile": "=concat(@(1,code),@(1,number),"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "eventInfo": "eventInfo",
      "mobile": {
        "": {
          "comment": [
            "if blank, do not pass mobile"
          ]
        },
        "*": {
          "@(2,mobile)": "eventData.Records.[0].mobile",
          "@(2,status)": {
            "A": {
              "#Active": "eventData.Records.[0].status"
            }
          },
          "@(2,country)": {
            "I": {
              "#India": "eventData.Records.[0].country"
            }
          },
          "@(2,pukcode)": {
            "": {
              "comment": [
                "if blank, do not pass mobile"
              ]
            },
            "*": "eventData.Records.[0].pukcode"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Output 2** :

```json
{
  "eventData": {
    "Records": [
      {
        "mobile": "+91-123456778",
        "status": "Active",
        "country": "India",
        "pukcode": null
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

pls provide some solution to the above

**Case 1
JSON Input** :

```json
{
  "code": "+91-",
  "status": "A",
  "number": "123456778",
  "country": "I",
  "pukcode": "00-766-54"
}
```

**Expected Output 1** :

```json
{
  "eventData": {
    "Records": [
      {
        "mobile": "+91-123456778",
        "status": "Active",
        "country": "India",
        "pukcode": "00-766-54"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Case 2 JSON Input** :

```json
{
  "code": "",
  "status": "A",
  "number": "",
  "country": "I",
  "pukcode": "00-766-54"
}
```

**Expected Output 2** :

```json
null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following transformation specs :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "number": {
        "*": {
          "@2,code|@1": "mobile",
          "@2,status": { "A": { "#Active": "status" } }, // renaming occurs here
          "@2,country": { "I": { "#India": "country" } },// and here
          "@2,pukcode": "pukcode"
        },
        "": { // if "number" is null then remove every element
          "": ""
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // concatenate the components of mobile array if it exists
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "mobile": "=join('',@(1,&))"
    }
  },
  { // nest the current object along with some keys as desired
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "eventData.Records[0].&"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Hi Barbaros Özhan,
Thank you for the input. your code is giving me case1 output.pls help me on below
sorry i have posted second case wrongly.
Condition:-
puk should get populate only if value in the input Json exist


Case 2 JSON Input :
{
  "code": "",
  "status": "A",
  "number": "",
  "country": "I",
  "pukcode": ""
}

Expected Output 1 :

{
  "eventData": {
    "Records": [
      {
        "mobile": "+91-123456778",
        "status": "Active",
        "country": "India"
      }
    ]
  }
}

Comment: Hi @krishdarling . This **completely** contradicts with the logic you have given. The cases were based on the existence of the value of number attribute. Btw, how can we derive the desired value "+91-123456778" from a "null" value ?
Moreover you should edit the question with the desired conditions rather than   
commenting here.